# Current Password checking with Angular JS + Laravel In Custom Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, laravel-4

I started a angular + laravel project yesterday and I stopped now with some error in angular.

here is my code.
HTML.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="CheckPawd">
  <label>Current Password</label>
  <input type="text" name="cpwd" ng-model="cpwd" ng-keyup="checkerPwd()" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Current Password" required>
  <p class="invalid" ng-show="!pwdChnge.cpwd.$pristine && pwdChnge.cpwd.$error.required">&#x21E7; Current Password is required</p>
  <p class="invalid" ng-show="checker">&#x21E7; Current Password is not matching</p>
</div>
```

Angular Controller.

```
app.controller('CheckPawd',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.checkerPwd = function(){
        $http({
        method:'post',
        url:'checkPwd',
        data:$.param({pwdd:$scope.cpwd})
    }).success(function (data,response){
    console.log(data);
    if(data=="1"){
        $scope.checker=null;
    }else{
        $scope.checker = data;
    }
    });
  };
});
```

Laravel Function.

```
public function checkPwd()
{
    if(Hash::check(Input::get('pwdd'), Auth::user()->password))
    {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This section is in change password area.
there are three fields are there,

Current password, New password, Confirm New Password

When User is entering current password i need to check that s valid with api.

How can I work with the custom validation rules..
With my above code I cant disable the submit button after getting the error in api calling result.

How can I solve this issue... ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to validate a password with a asnc $http request in angular i think is using a directive with async validator.

Here a good example http://www.codelord.net/2014/11/02/angularjs-1-dot-3-taste-async-validators/  how to add a validator to  ngModel.$asyncValidators .

Because checking password is an expensive operation i would suggest using ng-model-options  with debounce so that the check happen only all 500ms or on keyup https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

```
ng-model-options="{ debounce : { default : 500 } }"
```

or

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'keyup blur' }
```